# How to sell built Lego sets?

Tags: shopping, star-wars, value

I have 4 UCS Star Wars sets: Slave 1, Airspeeder, TIE fighter and Sandcrawler. I'm not interested in keeping them anymore. They take up a lot of room and don't do much.

I was wondering how to sell them: Ebay, Craigslist?

Any suggestions would be good. Also how much do you think they are worth (built)?

I have all of the mini-figures and no pieces are missing. I have the boxes and instructions.

Comment: Hi Alex and welcome to Bricks.SE! I don't know of any UCS SW sets called Air-speeder, did you perhaps mean the [Snowspeeder](https://brickset.com/sets/75144-1/Snowspeeder)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selling complete sets, Assembled or Disassembled?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11559/selling-complete-sets-assembled-or-disassembled)

Answer (score 3):

If the sets are indeed complete with all parts, minifigs, instructions and even boxes then I'd recommend Bricklink, as the collector community there would be more appreciative of these features. Whereas on Ebay and Craigslist you'd find more people who just want a playset and couldn't even tell if a set was complete or not.

For higher value sets (like yours) and for the european market I'd give Catawiki a look as well, as their reviewer and escrow system helps avoid scams and other pitfalls - for a higher fee for both buyers and sellers.

For price suggestions check these links below:

[Slave I](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75060-1#T=P)
[Sandcrawler](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75059-1#T=P)
[TIE Fighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75095-1#T=P)
[Snowspeeder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75144-1#T=P)

Comment: I think there is similar interest on EBay for these sets compared to BL. Many collectors use both venues to buy sets. EBay has a much larger audience than BL. That said, paypal and EBay together take ~20% of your proceeds as fees, whereas BL takes significantly less (~5%), so that larger audience comes at a price.

Comment: @PhilB. Thanks for the opinion and the numbers on the fees! In my experience Ebay tends to attract sellery and buyers with less interest and knowledge, but I do admit that there are certainly many serious collectors looking for bargain sales there as well.